# Unique identifier for objects with identical data fields that persists over multiple program executions

Tags: python, uniqueidentifier

I have a class `Entry`:

```
class Entry:
  def __init__(self, title, content, kw): 
    self.title = title                                
    self.content = content                            
    self.kw = kw
```

I am trying to generate a unique integer identifier for objects of `Entry` that I can store in an SQL database. The behaviour I am after is the following: If two objects of `Entry`, `a` and `b`, have identical values for their
`self.title, self.content, self.kw` fields, they will have the same id. Otherwise, they compute to different ids.

I understand that `id(e)` provides this functionality. However, it only lasts for the object's lifetime. Therefore, if I execute a program multiple times, where upon each execution of the program an `Entry` with exactly the same field values is instantiated (e.g `e = Entry(title='Hello', content='Hello world', kw='apples')`, `id(e)`can produce a different value every time.

I want the id of the object to remain the same over these multiple program executions. How do I get this functionality in python?

Thanks!

UPDATE:
I have found that I can actually set a unique constraint on multiple
columns of an SQL table, therefore, I can ensure that title, content and kw
is unique. However, content is a TEXT field, so I get the feeling this could
be quite inefficient. Accordingly, any answers that can compute the uniqueness
in python are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a hash:

```
import hashlib

class Entry:
    # other code

    def __hash__(self):
        data = "{}{}{}".format(self.title, self.content, self.kw)

        # return hash(data)
        return int.from_bytes(hashlib.blake2b(data.encode()).digest(), "big")
```

And then compare the hashes of the objects:

```
a, b = Entry(stuff1), Entry(stuff2)

if hash(a) != hash(b):
    print("Not equal!")
```

If you really, really care about hash collisions, which are really, really rare (for example, Google used huge clusters of CPUs and GPUs to find one single collision in SHA-1, which took [**110 years of GPU computation**](https://security.googleblog.com/2017/02/announcing-first-sha1-collision.html)), you can use BLAKE2b, which doesn't have any collision weaknesses by now and is [faster](https://research.kudelskisecurity.com/2017/03/06/why-replace-sha-1-with-blake2/) than MD5, and the SHA-1 and SHA-2 hashes.

To my mind, you could use Python's builtin `hash` just as well, with relatively small chances of collisions as these are very rare. Python uses `hash` in dictionaries and `set`s. Have you ever seen a collision in a dictionary? (Not saying it's impossible; it's just very rare). So, you should worry about collisions only if the users of your program might want to *search for them* on purpose.

Comment: I think this is not a good solution. The OP wants to use this number as a unique identifier, and while hash collisions are certainly very rare, I don't see a reason to take the risk. IMO it'd be better to manually assign an unused ID to each new combination of `title`, `content` and `kw`.

Comment: Yes, I thought about hashes, but as Aran-Fey says, collisions put me off.

Comment: @izaak_pyzaak, you can use a strong cryptographic hash (like SHA-3) if you're worried about collisions.

Comment: @Aran-Fey, how can you tell that some combination is new? You'd have to keep a potentially huge database of such combinations, then. And if you'd want to use this code on other machines, you'd have to copy this DB to them. Sounds a bit like blockchain, which consumes tens of gigs of storage.

Comment: That is true. You'd have to load all the objects from the database into memory to know which IDs are already taken.